# Based on a c# datetime, output the month as MM?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a datetime object (initialized), how can I output the month part as MM?

Answer (score 8):

```
Your_Date_Time_Object.ToString("MM")
```

Comment: You beat me to it. +1 for doing it in one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;              // Use current date
string format = "MM";                      // Use this format
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString(format));  // Write to console
```